# xserver-xorg-video-intel - 2:2.21.6 has a bug - how do I update?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics

I'm on raring and the xserver for my intel hardware (xserver-xorg-video-intel - 2:2.21.6) has a bug. Running pd (pure data) reliably crashes X. It's a known bug (see [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66104)) and it has been fixed in version 2:2.21.11.

I need pure data in Ubuntu for a project, so this bug really kills my work flow.

Is there any way to know, if there will be an update for raring to 2:2.21.11 or newer for raring? Or will I have to wait until October for saucy?

Cheers,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find this bug in the Ubuntu bug tracker:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bugs

What you need to do is file a bug about the issue in launchpad, and then link to that upstream bug with the fix so Ubuntu developers become aware.

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

And then to link it to the other bug tracker follow these instructions (the part about marking "Also affects"):

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToTriage#Forwarding_upstream

You can also bring the bug to the attention of the Ubuntu X developers themselves by checking out the [developer mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-x). Since the bug is a crasher and there is a known and tested fix upstream you have a good chance of that being backported/fixed for raring.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation for the bug-report.  Looking at x-edgers there is the newer version of the intel driver available.  Thus a backport is possible - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=raring.  Note - dont use this PPA unless you definitely know what you are doing and have read all of the PPA description first and have understood that it has the potential to eat both your Cat/Dog and Wife.

Comment: I just filed a bug in launchpad. Wait and see... Using a PPA for a core system component is a bit too much for me.